# Generate icacls script of permissions

Tags: windows, access-control-list

I am looking for a utility to which I can specify a directory to be recursively scanned. The utility should generate a batch file consisting of calls to `icacls` to reproduce the file and directory permissions under the specified path.

The `icacls /save` command is not suitable for this task particularly because it duplicates inherited permissions unnecessarily and it outputs SIDs instead of friendly account names.

Comment: So what do you want to do about inherited permissions then? Should permissions from parents be discarded? Does this also need to handle ownership in any manner?

Comment: @jscott, it should emit `(OI)(CI)` at the directory where the inherited entires are actually defined and the system will take care of the propagation.

Comment: So then it walks "up" from the directory provided. But surely you mean it should emit `(OI)(CI)` only at the directories which inherit "This folder, subfolders, and files", the other inherit modes `(OI)(CI)(IO)`, `(CI)(IO)`, and `(OI)(IO)` should be handled respectively.

Comment: Essentially, it should generate the minimum number of `icacls` calls to exactly reapply the original permissions. In the case that all entries on a specific directory or file are inherited entries, it should generate no `icacls` call for that directory or file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to apply the perms of a directory to it's children?
you can use powershell scripts for this. You can recursively scan directorys, and for each directory you can act on it, for example

```
Get-ChildItem C:\users\me\desktop -Recurse -Attributes Directory | foreach {Get-Acl $_.FullName | Format-List | Tee-Object C:\acls.list}
```

will recurse all directories in my desktop and output the permissions to the console and also to a file called C:\acls.list. You can also change ownership info, apply perms recursively, and pretty much whatever icalcs would do using `get-acl` and `set-acl`